# Error running substrate-node-template with Docker

Tags: substrate-node-template, docker

I downloaded substrate node template from [here](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template).

I am following the instructions given in the README and using following command to run the node in docker:

./scripts/docker_run.sh.

It give the following error:

"Error response from daemon: invalid mount config for type "bind": bind source path does not exist: /host_mnt/Users/syedkamran/polkadot/substrate-node-template/.local"

When I add an empty ".local" file the issue get resolved.

My questions here are:

1. What is the ".local" file for?
2. Is there any workaround so that the docker/bash commnad without including this ".local" file?
3. If this file is necessary than why they do not add this file to the souce code?

[image: Error screen shot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is looking for a .local/ folder but it doesn't exist.

I created [this PR](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/12901) to add that .local/ folder to the node-template (substrate-node-template) part of the [Substrate repository](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate) source code so users wouldn't get that error but the maintainers didn't want to merge it because they were in favour of the option of running substrate-node-template in a Docker container from the upstream [Substrate repository](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate) instead.

Note that [this issue](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/issues/396) highlights that the substrate-node-template repository is closed to PRs, otherwise I would have created a PR to add the missing .local/ folder into its source code too to fix that error.
Since you've highlighted that others like yourself are facing the same issue, I've suggested [here](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/issues/396#issuecomment-1480378828) that we remove all Docker related code from the [substrate-node-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template) repository and update its README to provide a link to the [substrate](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate) repository's [Docker instructions here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate#getting-started).

The [substrate-node-template](https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template) repository historically uses code from the [node-template section of the upstream Substrate repository](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/bin/node-template).

If you want to run the latest Substrate node-template in a Docker container, please follow the Substrate [Docker instructions here](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate#getting-started) instead.

Comment: Thank you very much @Luke for your time and detailed explanation . But can you please tel me: 1.  Why this .local file/folder is needed? 2. Is it Ok to add the .local file/folder?

Comment: the folder (not file) .local/ is required because that is where data such as session keys are stored for validators (see https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/1429/how-to-generate-keys-for-authorities). in the docker-compose.yml file here https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/docker-compose.yml#L15 we bind mount from the container folder /root/.local to the host machine project root folder ./.local. they also create a volume to /chain-data that has a symlink to /node-dev/.local/share/node-template, which is where session keys would be stored

Comment: _"cache for chain data in container"_ https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub/substrate-node-template/blob/main/.gitignore#L12

Comment: Sorry but I am unable to relate this with our discussion. I have marked your detailed explanation as answer BTW. Thank you for your time.